# Handling 3rd party popup windows within a Xamarin Forms WebView?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.webview

How can I handle popup windows from within a WebView?

The initial WebView displays a site from a third party, which in turn can trigger and should display a popup window based on the user's interaction within the webview.

Currently, the popup window fails to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webview does not support javascript. You will need to create custom control to achieve this. You can check those two articles to implement something that will suit your needs.

[Hybrid webview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview)

[Webview executing javascript](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-webview-executing-javascript/)