# How to invoke Google/Apple Pay from a Xamarin.Forms WebView?

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, applepay, google-pay

Is there a way to **enable Google/Apple Pay to be invoked from a WebView?** I'm using a payment service (similar to Stripe) that will gives me a payment URL. To finish a payment, I have to open a browser, navigate to that URL and let the user pay.

I'm using a WebView because I **need to be able to intercept the browser navigation** and close it when it's navigating to the return URL I've provided to the payment service. That's why I'm not opening the URL in a browser intent.

The problem is that when opened in a WebView, clicking on the Google Pay button **fails to open the Google Pay overlay** (where you can pick a card and pay) and the payment cannot be finished. I suspect that the WebView isn't able to invoke the Google Pay API, is there a way to enable that? If not, I'd have to switch to opening the payment URL in a browser intent (using the Xamarin.Essentials's Browser API) and I'd lose the option to intercept the browser navigation.

Thanks for any advice!

**EDIT:**

I've received advice from the my payment processor in the meantime. They said:

*Use the `Chrome Custom Tabs` for Android instead of the `WebView`. It works similarly but also supports standard functionality (such as Google Pay). To use Apple Pay on iOS, use the `SFSafariController`.*

I'll try that and report back here.

Comment: I can't ensure the cause of `fails to open the Google Pay overlay` is the webview not support 3 part popup or not. You can try to custom the webview renderder such as [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60654960/handling-3rd-party-popup-windows-within-a-xamarin-forms-webview). In addition, you can try to use the libs in your project such as the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023320/how-to-integrate-google-pay-in-my-android-app-for-payment).

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Thanks! I'll check that out.

Comment: But when I search on the internet, I found that most of the payment on android use the  Stripe sdk in their projects. It seems that there are some limits in the webview.

Comment: I've noticed that too, however, my payment processor doesn't have a Xamarin SDK.

Comment: So you may need to use the Xamarin libs in your project just like the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3a865ed-373f-482c-9ddb-f7fe57f44b7c/how-to-integrate-apply-pay-and-google-pay-in-xamarin-forms?forum=xamarinforms) I provided.